# jquery form not gettin submitted

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is the script i have written to submit the form after validation and receive the values in php file using $_POST but i am not getting values in php file. when i try to echo that values its showing blank in php.Please guide me i am new to jquery

```
<script>
$("#changepassform").validate({


  rules: {
    old_password: "required",
    password: "required",
    password2: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    },
  },
  messages: {

    old_password: "Please enter old password",

    password: "Please enter new password",
    password2: " Enter Confirm Password Same as Password"

  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

      var current_password = $("#current_password").val();
      var new_password = $("#password").val();
      var comfirm_password = $("#password2").val();
      var id = $("#id").val();
      var dataString = 'newpassword1=' + new_password + '&id1=' + id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changepassword.php",
        data: "dataString",
        success: function(response) {

          $("#status").html(response);
        }
      });

    }
    //form.submit();

  //return false;  

});
// required to block normal submit since you used ajax
//form.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: change  data: "dataString" to  data: dataString,

Comment: instead of `data: "dataString",` update `data: dataString,` and try to parse the form.

Comment: Thank you my friend prakash but whats the reason behind not quoting dataString...answer will be appreciated

Comment: When you use quotes, it is considered as string. But you are passing a variable

Comment: @Hemant, dataString is variable and in that variable you are already assigning string. So, no need to quoting that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error at sending data..

```
<script>
    $("#changepassform").validate({


      rules: {
        old_password: "required",
        password: "required",
        password2: {
          equalTo: "#password"
        },
      },
      messages: {

        old_password: "Please enter old password",

        password: "Please enter new password",
        password2: " Enter Confirm Password Same as Password"

      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {

          var current_password = $("#current_password").val();
          var new_password = $("#password").val();
          var comfirm_password = $("#password2").val();
          var id = $("#id").val();
          var dataString = 'newpassword1=' + new_password + '&id1=' + id;

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "changepassword.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response) {

              $("#status").html(response);
            }
          });

        }
        //form.submit();

      //return false;  

    });
    // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
    //form.submit();
    </script>
```

Use `serialize()` method.The serialized values can be used in the URL query string when making an AJAX request.